# Sitecore solr setup in a different VM

Tags: solr, sitecore, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I have created 2 VMs, one for Sitecore and one for SOLR server. This is the [article](http://www.norconex.com/how-to-run-solr5-as-a-service-on-windows/) I was referencing when setting up the SOLR server. I'm able to open up SOLR Admin page using localhost within SOLR server instance. But I failed to access it from Sitecore Server using VIP or internal IP. Both of them are in the same VNet subset. Am I missing something here? Or the SOLR setup is not done properly?

Resolved: Based on azure documentation, I will need to manually open up the firewall port.

> Firewall configuration for Azure virtual machines is done automatically for ports associated with Remote Desktop and Secure Shell (SSH), and in most cases for Windows PowerShell Remoting. For ports specified for all other endpoints, no configuration is done automatically to the firewall of the virtual machine. When you create an endpoint for the virtual machine, you'll need to ensure that the firewall of the virtual machine also allows the traffic for the protocol and private port corresponding to the endpoint configuration.

Comment: Did you open up all the required ports in Azure?

Comment: Yes, I have enabled endpoint 8983 for both Sc and SOLR server instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure access to the endpoint on Azure VM you should:

- Add endpoint in Azure Portal ([link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-classic-setup-endpoints/))
- Configure Windows Firewall on VM ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh168549(v=nav.90).aspx))

These two steps should be enough to access to SOLR on Azure VM.

Please, check that the endpoint for 8983 port is added to the VM.